# adding successive movements after setting a chessboard in a certain position

Tags: chess

After setting up a chessboard for a certain position using 
 [\chessboard[setfen=, showmover]]

Is it possible to add successive movements for the rest of the game for example using \mainline{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `\newchessgame` to correctly initialize a game that you want to play with `\mainline`. You can pass the fen position to it, but I do find it more natural to do it the other way round and pass the start position from `\newchessgame` to a board.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{tinyboard}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\minisec{Game1}
\newchessgame[
 white=Harry Red,
 black=Tom Green,
 result=1-0,
 setfen=k1K1R,
 moveid=20b,
 print %print the startboard
 ]

\mainline{20...  Ka7 21. Re6 Ka8 22. Ra6#}

\chessboard

\minisec{Game2}
\chessboard  [setfen=k2K3Q,storefen=myname]
\newchessgame[restorefen=myname]

\mainline{1. Kc7 Ka7 2. Qa1#}

\chessboard
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]